# NGX-chart show Time line issue. When load component dynamically using ComponentPortal in angular 8 version

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

show timeline issue when load the ngx charts using dynamically load component using ComponentPortal in angular 8 version. Please provide the solutions.

Rendring component using  in loop Like :

```html
<ng-template class="custom-area margin-10" [cdkPortalOutlet]="dynamicComponentList[element.id]"></ng-template>
```

Comment: I don't think there is enough context in this post to understand what you are trying to accomplish. Would you be able to provide some sample code that show's what you've attempted? Not just the ng-template from within your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Install the ndc-dynamic package and Use ndc-dynamic for render dynamic component. You can also send the Input or Output decorator. It's working fine for me.